# Rails: scopes with joins in has_many through

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am trying to create a role system in Rails 4:

A User is a user account.
A Project is a thing that multiple users might edit.

A Role is the thing that links users with projects. A rule has a `user_id`, a `project_id` and a `role_type_id`.

Depending on the `rank` of the roleType, a user might have more permissions for a certain project.

now, I am trying to set up the relations between these models. However, the SQL-queries that are generated seem wrong. What am I missing?

project.rb:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles, -> {user_roles.eager_load(:role_type)}, class_name: "Role"
  has_many :users, through: :user_roles
  has_many :admin_roles, -> {admin_roles}, class_name: "Role"
  has_many :admins, through: :admin_roles, source: :users
  has_many :creator_roles, -> {creator_roles}, class_name: "Role"
  has_many :creators, through: :creator_roles, source: :user
end
```

role.rb:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :role_type

  scope :user_roles,    ->{eager_load(:role_type).where("role_types.rank = 1").select("roles.*,role_types.*")}
  scope :admin_roles,   ->{eager_load(:role_type).where("role_types.rank = 2").select("roles.*,role_types.*")}
  scope :creator_roles, ->{eager_load(:role_type).where("role_types.rank = 3").select("roles.*,role_types.*")}
end
```

Calling `Project.first.user_roles` (or #admin_roles or #creator_roles) works fine. But calling `Project.first.users` (or #admins or #creators) creates the following error:

```
  2.2.1 :007 > Project.first.users
  Project Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects"  ORDER BY "projects"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "roles" ON "users"."id" = "roles"."user_id" WHERE "roles"."project_id" = ? AND (role_types.rank = 1)  [["project_id", 1]]
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: role_types.rank: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "roles" ON "users"."id" = "roles"."user_id" WHERE "roles"."project_id" = ? AND (role_types.rank = 1)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: role_types.rank: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "roles" ON "users"."id" = "roles"."user_id" WHERE "roles"."project_id" = ? AND (role_types.rank = 1)
```

I have tried all of `joins()`, `includes()` and `eager_load()` as well as using a `default_scope` that joins the rank_types table with the ranks one. But the problem stays the same.

It seems that when using the `has_many :through` relation, the `eager_load()` specified in the scope is not added to the generated SQL. Is this a limitation of Rails or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can't give a good solution or explanation at the moment, but why not use [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) gem for introducing role-system in you application? I've been using this so far everywhere where role-based users are needed and I'm very satisfied with it.

Comment: I thought that CanCanCan was only to handle static permissions (i.e. not resource-specific). It seems I was mistaken. I will definitely check it out.

Nonetheless, I would like this question to be answered, as the permissions case above is just one of multiple situations in which this problem might appear.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the lambda syntax for `has_many`, however it appears that you're `eager_load`-ing `role_type` twice. Once in the scope, and once in the association that calls that scope.

Comment: What about something like `has_many :user_roles, -> { joins(:role_type).where("role_types.rank = 1") }, class_name: 'Role'`

Comment: And SQL needs single-=, not double-==. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where

Comment: @LannyBose I have tried the `has_many :user_roles, -> { joins(:role_type).where("role_types.rank = 1") }, class_name: 'Role'` statement, which gives me the same error.

Thanks for the heads-up about SQL needing only single-equals signs. It's been a while. Code in the question has been updated with this change.